# Are Triggers Based On Queries Atomic?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table that has a Sequence number. This sequence number will change and referencing the auto number will not work. I fear that the values of the trigger will collide. If two transactions read at the same time.

I have ran simulated tests on 3 connections @ ~1 million records each and no collisions.

```
CREATE TABLE `aut` (
  `au_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `au_control` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `au_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `did` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`au_id`),
  KEY `Did` (`did`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

```
TRIGGER `binc_control` BEFORE INSERT ON `aut` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.AU_CONTROL = (SELECT COUNT(did)+1 FROM aut WHERE did = NEW.did);
END;
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)+1` --- it's a really bad idea. What `au_control` should refer to?

Comment: If collision can be a problem, creating a `UNIQUE(did, au_control)` seems wise. I'm not sure whether selects in triggers are atomic, I would assume they're _not_.

Comment: You could define your `PRIMARY KEY(did,au_control)` though, with the second one as auto increment fields, but it has some drawbacks (1) you lose the `au_id` column, but a real primary key instead of a surrogate might be better, (2) the table would _have_ to be MyISAM, as InnoDB doesn't support it, which has serious drawbacks. [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31788/1)

Comment: @Wrikken I appreciate your answers. I didn't know MyIsam could behave like that. The challenge I have with the fiddle is that I lose the capability to uniquely identify the record. To use this approach I now need to reference both the sequence and the DID. When updating the Sequence number I may lose site of my record in the event of an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is subject to race conditions if two sessions run the trigger at the same time. You shouldn't use this solution.

It may not happen during testing, but you can assume it *will* happen during production. :-)

There's an old saying, [One in a million is next Tuesday](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. It's atomic, and the initial statement plus all side effects are committed as the same transaction.

But then, anything can go wrong with your query depending on the isolation level. MySQL has a cached value in the catalog if memory serves, but this cache can potentially become stale if you're reading it with non-serializable isolation in concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Even within an explicit isolated transaction, there is still a race condition where you can end up with duplicate au_control values.  count(*) is going to be horrible for performance.  There are better ways to get a monotonically increasing guid if that is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `UUID_SHORT()` function might be useful to you.  It is atomic and generates an ever_incrementing `BIGINT UNSIGNED` value every time it is called, subject to the requirement that you don't stop the server, set the clock backwards in time to a time prior to or close to the previous start (depending on how often you call it) and start the server again, or change the value of `@@server_id` to a value whose LSB is lower.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short