# Updating sum of an order after item insert

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am not sure how to do this since I am new to sql and databases. I have a bit of trouble with understanding how the for each row in trigger works. Basically I have a 3 tables that are important in this trigger.

```
Item(Item_ID (pk), price, ...more attributes )

Receipt( Receipt_ID (pk), total_sum,.. more attributes )

Bought(Item_ID (pk), Receipt_ID (pk))
```

I hope this clarifies how the table looks like. Did not add all the other attributes since I think they are not important. Basically what I want to do with the trigger is if I insert an element into bought I would add the price of that element to the total sum of the receipt. But I am not quite sure at this point how to do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_sum
AFTER INSERT ON bought
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  UPDATE Receipt
  SET total_sum = total_sum + 
  WHERE
END;
```

This is where I am stuck

Comment: Your schema is fairly clear, but can you share any code with us?

Comment: Storing the sum of the order would be a design error (transitive dependency). You should search and read about "normalization"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @iDevlop yes I know this is the case but since I would use the total sum a lot I thought it would be nice to have it as an attribute

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi I updated it at first I did not share it since I got stuck really fast and thought it would not help much

Comment: Even if the trigger be logically correct, I'm not sure [that it would be atomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505581/are-triggers-based-on-queries-atomic).  Instead, you might be leaning towards running those two inserts inside a transaction.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok thank you will try to do that :)

Comment: Please check my comment to the answer and my answer as well. I am worried that you will have issues due to concurrency.

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you I think you explained it really well now I know what I will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordon Linoff already pointed out you need `:new` to achieve what you want and also you need to handle delete and update as well in triggers. However, the solution would not be really safe, as if there are many inserts, updates and deletes in a short period of time, there is a chance that an older event will run after the newest event. To cope with this situation you might want to fully calculate the sum in your trigger instead of adding a numerical number to the sum. You could define a stored procedure for this purpose which will update Receipt based on the actual sum.

However, this idea might be generating a lot of overload for your database, so it might be better not to use triggers for this purpose, but implement a stored procedure which will make the necessary updates and call it once per minute in a cron job. The advantage of this solution is that you have a fairly new value which is maximum one-minute-old and will not really have a negative impact on your performance. Its disadvantage is that you do not really update the value real-time. If the disadvantage is too large, then you might call this stored procedure in specific cases when you need real-time values.

A further improvement is to have a `to_update` column for `Receipts` and to have insert/update/delete triggers updating this specific value to mark what needs to be updated and to only `update` the records to be updated. If you choose this approach, do not forget to actually update `to_update` as well to make sure you will not always `update` values which were already updated and unchanged since then.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want `:new`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_sum
AFTER INSERT ON bought
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Receipt
      SET total_sum = (total_sum +
                       (select i.price from items i where i.item_id = :new.item_id)
                      )
      WHERE receipt_id = :new.receipt_id
END;
```

However, I would suggest that you do the calculation when you need to, rather than storing the sum.  If you do store the sum, you definitely need a "delete" trigger as well, and probably an "update" trigger.

Comment: Nice answer, but I believe this could fail to yield the correct results in case of concurrency. When an older record's insertion trigger runs before the newer insertion trigger, you add a number to a deprecated value. It is safer not to assume that total_sum is new and to do the whole calculation. It might affect performance badly, so a trigger is not necessarily the best option as you have pointed out as well.