# Obtaining a combined key (year/number) in mysql with innoDB storage engine

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, auto-increment

I would like to create a combined key in an innoDB table that already has an "ID" column with auto incrementing value that works as primary key.

Assuming we have the following "test_table" inside "test_db":

[image]

I made the "inc year_num" trigger for "test_table":

```
SET New.num_field := IFNULL(
  ( SELECT  MAX(num_field)+1
        FROM  test_table
        WHERE  year_field = New.year_field ), 1)
```

This trigger ("before insert") seems to work well:

[image]

However il leaves me with a doubt: in case of multiple simultaneous insertions, could it generate identical combined keys (year/number), even if with different "IDs"?
If so, how can I resolve the problem?

Another question: will using this trigger slow down table work, considering use in a multi-user environment?

Comment: I don't foresee a problem, but for reassurance (and a performance gain), you could add a unique key on `(year_field, num_field)`

Comment: @RobEyre thanks for suggestion. I've done.
So you think there aren't problems about possible errors?

Comment: According to [this (old) Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19505581/), _"this is subject to race conditions"_. If you add the unique key suggested by RobEyre, you can detect the duplicate key error and retry.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with multiple threads, use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
get the new num_field
put that value into the table
etc
COMMIT;
```

It seems unnecessary to have `id`; simply have `PRIMARY KEY(year_field, num_field)`.

Another note:  `ZEROFILL` will be removed in a later version of MySQL.  (It was 'deprecated' in 8.0.17.)  There are simple workarounds.

You will almost never need an isolation level other than the default, so ignore that lesson (for now).

One transaction may *or may not* wait for the other to finish.  Individual *rows* are locked; if there are no conflicting locks, then two transactions can proceed in parallel.

`TRIGGER` and `PROCEDURE` are orthogonal features.  For example, a Trigger can contain all the SQL statements needed, or it could call a Procedure that encapsulates the statements.

Comment: Thanks.
I'm just getting into MySQL and I'm not familiar with transactions.
Yesterday I studied the subject a bit and I understood that there are 4 levels of isolation.
Can you explain what the correct isolation level is for my case and how to set it?
If I understand correctly, I need each transaction doesn't start until the previous has completed. I need to change delimiter? If/else, rollback? I would be really grateful if you would post the correct code. One last thing: will the code go directly into the trigger or I need to create a stored procedure with a trigger that calls it?

Comment: @Alex - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Sorry @RickJames I promise you it's my last messagge.

If two simultaneous transactions (T1 and T2) need to insert a row, each will search for the maximum value of 'num_field' where the value of 'year_field' is equal to the one to be inserted. Imagining that the value to be inserted of 'year_field' is '2023' and that the maximum value of 'num_field' with year equal to '2023' is '5', it is impossible that both will take this value by both trying to write '2023' in 'year_field' and '6' in 'num_field', raising an error for violating the combined field uniqueness rule?

Comment: @Alex - Any `SELECTs` inside the transaction may need a `FOR UPDATE` clause on the end.  This is especially for "get the new num_field" --> `SELECT MAX(num_field)+1 FROM tbl FOR UPDATE`.  This alerts that other transactions that something is going on with `num_field`.